# Hadoop MapRed default config

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2

I have a Hadoop 2.7.2 cluster which I'm trying to run a DFSIO test. If I leave mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml untouched, will the MapRed be set to classic MapRed (V1) by default?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you leave mapred-site.xml and yarn-site.xml untouched, MapRed V1 (classic) will be used by default.